# Bottle Headspace Problem

Tags: bottling, headspace

I bottled my beer two days ago, primed with honey as per the instructions of my all-grain kit. I've since been reading and found you need to leave about an inch of headspace in the bottles. Unfortunately I did not know this at the time and have filled the bottles to the brim.

Is it ok to open the bottles and let some beer out to get this headspace or will that ruin the beer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that, but you will lose a bit of the CO2 that has been produced. Assuming you cap, you will have to recap with new (sanitized) caps.

If you work clean this should not give you any problems.

Comment: I opened a couple of the bottles and they seem very carbonated after only two days, lots of foam trying to get out so I screwed the lid shut again (using plastic PET bottles). Not really sure what to do now... :S

Comment: if they are already very carbonated, move them to a fridge. Since you used PET bottles, you should not have any issues with bottle bombs, but they will continue to carbonate and upon opening will be like a champagne bottle and whatever beer you do manage to get into a glass will be flat (go figure).